# How to remove Duplicates from ResultSet in java

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, duplicates, resultset

In database mapRule column contains

1. Deep partial thickness burn of toe(s) (disorder)
2. Second degree burn of toe (disorder)
3. Superficial partial thickness burn of foot (disorder)
4. Second degree burn of toe (disorder)
5. Deep partial thickness burn of toe(s) (disorder)
6. Deep partial thickness burn of toe(s) (disorder)

I have to remove duplicates and need the output like this

1. Deep partial thickness burn of toe(s) (disorder)
2. Second degree burn of toe (disorder)
3. Superficial partial thickness burn of foot (disorder)

how to get this ? i am fetching data from mysql & my code is

## CODE

```
<%
            pstm = Con.prepareStatement(selectsql);
            pstm.setString(1, snomedid);
            resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String[] pipe = resultSet.getString("mapRule").split("\\|");
                if (pipe.length > 1) { 
        %>

    <p><%=pipe[1]%></p>
    <%
        }
        }
    %>
```

How to remove duplicates from resultset ?

Comment: Put the results in a `Set<String>`.

Comment: An even better idea: make the database return only distinct values in the proper order. It's his job.

Comment: Simplest way is to do it at the sql query level.

Comment: @gonzo colud u explain how to do ?

Comment: @Kayaman i should not do with sql query thats a problem and i confused

Answer (score 0):

You should really be handling this on the database side with your query but here is a quick example and short explanation on `Set`.

A `Set` is a collection that handles duplicates automatically for you. So instead of saving your results to a `String[]`, then removing the duplicates, try saving them to a `Set<String>` instead.

```
   String[] results = {"a", "b", "a"}; //This is just dummy data
   Set<String> resultsInSet = new HashSet<>();
   for (String result: results){
       resultsInSet.add(result); //This is how you add a new element to the set
   }
   //You can loop through a set just like an array
   for (String result: resultsInSet){
       System.out.println(result);
   }
   System.out.println(resultsInSet); //And print the whole set like this
```

Output:

```
a
b
[a, b]
```

If you are using the shiny new Java 8, then you can even do this without `Sets` and just use a `Stream` after you get all of your results in one `String[]`. Here is a quick way to do that:

```
   String[] results = {"a", "b", "a"}; //This is just dummy data
   String[] uniqueResults = Arrays.stream(results).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(uniqueResults));
```

Comment: @bala you add an element to a set with the `add()` method. Please look at the example.